# How do I find the sum of inequalities by unique group/subgroup pairs?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I am working with the following `data.table`:

```
dta <- setDT(
  data.frame(
    id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
    subid = c(1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1),
    x1 = c(1,1,3,1,2,3,3,3),
    x2 = c(3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3)
  )
)

> dta
   id subid x1 x2
1:  A     1  1  3
2:  A     1  1  3
3:  A     2  3  1
4:  B     1  1  1
5:  B     2  2  1
6:  C     1  3  3
7:  C     1  3  3
8:  C     1  3  3
```

For each unique `id`-`subid` pairing, I would like to find the total number of times that `x1<x2` and the total number of times that `x1>=x2`, and have those counts be added to the data.table as new columns/variables but aggregated to the id level.

The outcome would look something like:

```
   id subid x1 x2 lt gt
1:  A     1  1  3  1  1
2:  A     1  1  3  1  1
3:  A     2  3  1  1  1
4:  B     1  1  1  0  2
5:  B     2  2  1  0  2
6:  C     1  3  3  0  1
7:  C     1  3  3  0  1
8:  C     1  3  3  0  1
```

For example, of the two unique `id-subid`parings for `id="A"`, one has `x1<x2` and one has `x1>x2`, which means that for `A` the variable for "less-than" has a value of 1 (i.e. `dta$lt[dta$id==A] <- 1`), and the same for "greater-than" (`dta$gt[dta$id==A] <- 1`).

I have been searching for a solution to this but have not had much luck. I *have* found solutions to similar problems (e.g. counting number of unique observations by unique pairings), but have not been able to modify them to suit my needs. In particular, I am struggling to aggregate the count from the `id-subid` level to the `id` level. (It could be that I'm not exactly sure how to search for -- or even word -- this question.)

I've been able to do this using nested loops on a data frame, but I suspect there is a more efficient way of doing it. In particular, I am curious about doing this using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

Comment: Do you need  `dta[, c('lt', 'gt') := .(sum(x1 < x2), sum(x1 >= x2)), .(id, subid)]`

Comment: @akrun Close, but I need `lt` and `gt` to display the sum at the `id` level and only for each unique `id-subid` row/observation. For example, "A-1" is in `dta` twice, but should only be summed once.

Comment: Maybe `dta[, c('lt', 'gt') := unique(.SD)[, .(sum(x1 < x2), sum(x1 >= x2))], by = .(id, subid)]`?

Comment: Are those values correct in 'lt' and 'gt.  You may do `dta[,   c('lt', 'gt') := .(sum((x1 < x2) & !duplicated(x1)), sum((x1 >=x2) & !duplicated(x1))), .(id, subid)]`

Comment: These are close, but they don't aggregate the sums to the `id` level. That is, for `id == A` `lt` should give me the total number of times that `x1<x2` across all unique `id-subid` pairs  (i.e. `A-1` and `A-2`).

Comment: A small adaptation of my previous solution: `dta[, c('lt', 'gt') := unique(.SD)[, .(sum(x1 < x2), sum(x1 >= x2))], by = .(id)][]`

Comment: I think your `subid` part was confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
dta[, c('lt', 'gt') := unique(.SD)[, .(sum(x1 < x2), sum(x1 >= x2))], by = .(id)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dta
>    id subid x1 x2 lt gt
> 1:  A     1  1  3  1  1
> 2:  A     1  1  3  1  1
> 3:  A     2  3  1  1  1
> 4:  B     1  1  1  0  2
> 5:  B     2  2  1  0  2
> 6:  C     1  3  3  0  1
> 7:  C     1  3  3  0  1
> 8:  C     1  3  3  0  1
> ```

Comment: I tried this on my full data set and at first it did not aggregate at the `id` level, but when I appended `.SDcols` to the end and specified the columns of interest, it ended up working. I guess the other columns in the `data.table` were messing things up. At any rate -- thank you!

Comment: @lante Yeah, if you have more columns, then yuo definitely need to specify `.Sdcols`.